# Share virtual machine between Windows7 and OSX

Tags: windows-7, macos, virtual-machine, boot-camp

I would like to be able to access an Ubuntu virtual machine from both Bootcamp Windows 7 and OSX.  The best way I can think of doing this is by putting the image on a external drive.  However, I'd rather not have to carry the external everywhere I go.

Is there an easier way of accessing the image in both operating systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put it on an external device, but this is liable to be pretty slow to access.

It might be possible to repartition the hard drive and create a new partition, with a file system that can be accessed by OSX and Windows 7.

The VM could then be copied over to the common partition and be accessed from both operating systems.

Comment: I like that idea. What format? Probably just FAT? Thanks a lot

Comment: FAT32 would be more appropriate, but yes.

Comment: Well yes, that's what i was referring to. I just didnt put the 32 :P

Answer (score 1):

An external hard drive using SATA or USB 2.0 can actually produce a snappier virtual environment than running a virtual machine from the same hard drive as your host operating system as both operating systems will then compete for access of the same drive.

It does however have both the benefit and drawback of being external. An extra toy to carry around, but it is movable (to other computers if wanted).